# Object on master slide not applying to slides on PowerPoint (not text)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PDF that I've converted to PPT. I want to add a partner's logo to the footer of the document (image file, no text). However, when I add the logo to the master slide, it either doesn't appear at all or only appears on some slides.

I've tried resetting the layout, adding new sub-masters, but it seems really hit or miss. The document is 18 pages.

I've googled but can only find things that address text formatting in the master.

Comment: This seems like a tech support issue to me, but you have to add the logo to the master master slide. (does that make sense?) The one at the very top of the hierarchy.

Comment: This would greatly depend upon the structure of the "converted" slides. it's not impossible that some slides have a slide-covering image on them to maintain some of the PDF appearance.